# How to write recursive search with numpy where function?

Tags: python, numpy, recursion, indexing

Im writing a recursive function to find pairs of indices.
In my example, the vectors i and j, are the i and j indices of nonzero elements of a matrix.

Now i wanted to find "unique" pairs of indices, so i can make sort a matrix in its diagonal form. Or at least eliminate zero elements

Ive wrote a function with numpy.

```py
import numpy as np

i = np.array([0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 4, 4, 5, 5, 6, 6, 6, 7, 7, 8, 8])
j = np.array([0, 3, 4, 0, 2, 4, 1, 5, 2, 6, 8, 3, 8, 4, 5, 7, 4, 6, 7, 8])
numbers = np.array([-1.])

def iterate(i, j, iter, numbers):
    ii, = np.where(i == iter)
    jj, = np.where(j[ii] != numbers)

    try:
        for jjj in jj:
            numbers = np.append(numbers, [jjj])
            if iter < np.amax(i)+1:
                iterate(i, j, iter+1, numbers)
            else:
                return numbers
    except:
        print("exception")
```

I would expect a return if my iteration variable exceeds the length of the highest values in i.
Problem is numpy is throwing an error for a multiple compare operation:

```py
jj, = np.where(j[ii] != numbers)
```

Comment: What's the error?  `jj,=...` only works when the `where` tests a 1d array.  That unpacking comma is unforgiving.

Comment: ```python __main__:11: DeprecationWarning: elementwise != comparison failed; this will raise an error in the future. ```

Comment: What's `numbers` and `j[ii]` at the point?

Answer (score 0):

By adding a `print` right after the `ii,=` line I see that `numbers` is `[-1,0]`, and:

```
In [76]: j[[3,4,5]]                                                             
Out[76]: array([0, 2, 4])
In [77]: j[[3,4,5]]!=np.array([-1,0])                                           
/usr/local/bin/ipython3:1: DeprecationWarning: elementwise comparison failed; this will raise an error in the future.
  #!/usr/bin/python3
Out[77]: True
```

It doesn't like comparing a 3 element array with a 2 element one.  In the past it has tolerated the mismatch, but in the future it will be disallowed.

What are you trying to do here?  With each append `numbers` gets longer, but `j[ii]` will vary depending on `i`.

Are you looking for an exact match between two arrays?  Elementwise?  A 2d cartesian match?

Comment: I want to take only one unique integer from j, for all i.

For example im Checking the 0 integer from i, so i have three options a choice from j. This would take the 0 from j and appends it to numbers. The next iteration checks i and gets 1, now it should look for a partner in j, and 0 is already take, so i want to check for integers in position of i=1, which arent 0. And so on.
Condition would be to be longer than then max value of i.